# How to include 3rd party libraries in Go on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I want to use the pdf library https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gofpdf. I only have the GAE SDK for Go installed and nothing else. i would like to be able to do:

```
import "code.google.com/p/gofpdf"
```

I have a feeling the entire library has to be downloaded into my codebase?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use third party libraries   in go 
you usually us the **go -get command**
In your case it wil be

```
go get code.google.com/p/gofpdf
```

I suggest that you will this this  doc on go

[How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: Tried this in my Go project source and got "package code.google.com/p/gofpdf: unable to detect version control system for code.google.com/ path"

Comment: Since pdf didn't work I tried go get github.com/revel/revel instead. The result was a compile error "Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "syscall" in src\golang.org\x\net\ipv4\payload_nocmsg.go". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first error is because you don't have the proper version control installed, you probably need to install mercurial. The second is because appengine restricts what can be used. The syscall package is one which is restricted. unsafe is also disallowed.